# Faqified or faqificated

Tags: verbs, adjectives, tenses

This may sound like a strange question, but I couldn't find an answer online anywhere, so I thought I should ask it here on **English Language & Usage**.

I recently went through a couple of questions on the [meta.dba.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/) site and added the [<kbd>faq-proposed</kbd>](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) (*click to see the meta questions*) tag. I was proposing that some questions become common FAQ questions for the benefit of the community.

Today I greeted my fellow colleagues on our DBA chat The Heap™ with the message:

> *Musing of a Mumbler* If a meta post is to become an FAQ tagged post, has the post then been ***faqified*** or ***faqificated***?

Searching Google for "faqified or faqificated" produces three results, all not related to my initial question.

## Questions

#### Verbs

I am genuinely interested whether the process of changing the state of a meta question to be an FAQ is to be qualified with **has been faqificated** or **has been faqified** or not?

#### Adjectives

Would one then say: ***This is a faqificated question*** or rather ***This is a faqified quesiton***?

## Summary

Reading the sentence and just feeling what has been written, I would lean towards: ***faqified***, but I couldn't explain why.

Another question which arises is whether an additional ***u***  would be required after the ***q*** to produce ***faquified***?

An explanation from the community would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google shows faqified (or FAQified) is more common but both are rare and not in dictionaries. "faqified" is also simpler, and I think some grammarians would object to -ificated on the grounds that it's longer and less natural. There's probably no need to add a U as there's none in FAQ; but you can spell it FAQified to make it clearer. The suffix "-ify" is productive and so can be used to form new word. Without a dictionary blessing one form, I'm not sure how to get a definitive answer.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_productive_suffixes

Comment: Both are neologisms.  Which one is more "correct" is purely a matter of personal choice.

Comment: _Neither_ seems to be even a neologism. A neologism is a new word, and there has to be some form of consensus that a candidate has been worded before it can be considered part of the lexis and thus standard English.